# OpsCenter - funny showing different Ring graphical representation

Tags: opscenter

I've got a OpsCenter watching three clusters, two v.2.0 and one v.2.1. Am wondering why the 2.1 cluster is shown as [bars](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13225502/opscenter_cass2-1_ring.tiff) on a circle, when v.2.0 quite differently is shown as [dots](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13225502/opscenter_cass-2-0_ring.tiff) on the circle, why the difference? Can't remember now the initial version of OpsCenter that started out just monitoring the v.2.1, then later the v.2.0 was added and showed up as dots. Any symbolic meaning in this?

Answer (score 0):

The Ring View in OpsCenter has two modes for rendering:  vnode and non-vnode.  The latter will show a circle for each individual node positioned based on its single token range.  The former will display each node as a "slice" of the ring based on its percentage of data held in that data center.

More information on Ring View can be found here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/online_help/opscNodeAdminRing.html

More information on vnodes can be found here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html

Comment: Thanks, yes also figured this out by now as we have chosen to alter all our clusters to anode-mode, they shows a slices.